# How to count how many attribute name&values by user wrote in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to make a function which counts how many attributes I have with Attribute name&value I entered in html.

I don't know how to count by Attribute name&value!

like when i put "type" and "text" in this html then show 2!

I am very new to javascript! if you help me it would be very thankful! thanks

```js
function javascript_click() { 
  if (document.getElementById("value3").value && document.getElementById("value4").value ) {
    var attName=document.getElementById("value3").value;
    var attValue=document.getElementById("value4").value;
    if((attName && attValue) !==''){
      var val3 = document.getElementById("value3");}
    else {
      document.getElementById("cnt").innerHTML += 
      "wrong value of ID <br>";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <table class="tg" id="tg">
    <tr>
      <td>Attribute name</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="value3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>attribute value</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="value4"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div id="cnt"></div>
</form>
<div class="button">
  <button id='btn_javascript' onclick="javascript_click();">javascript</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Please reformulate. What exactly is that function supposed to do?

Comment: Seems to me like you want to use the [required](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-required) attribute? you can also supplement the input with min/max length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understand you right

```
    function javascript_click() {
  if (document.getElementById("value3").value && document.getElementById("value4").value) {
    var attName = document.getElementById("value3").value;
    var attValue = document.getElementById("value4").value;
    var value = "[" + attName + "=" + attValue + "]";
    var num2 = document.querySelectorAll(value).length;
    document.getElementById("cnt").innerHTML += "선택하신 노드는 " + num2 + "개 입니다. By javascript<br>";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("cnt").innerHTML += "wrong value of ID <br>";
  }
}
    <form action="">
  <table class="tg" id="tg">
    <tr>
      <td>Attribute name</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="value3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>attribute value</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="value4"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div id="cnt"></div>
</form>
<div class="button">
  <button id='btn_javascript' onclick="javascript_click();">javascript</button>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! but when i put this javascript code to another html it doesn't work .. I think because of ${attName.length*2} this part is static!?....

Comment: Any errors in the console? 

`\`...${attName.length*2}<br>\``; just template literal; another way would be concatination:
`let result = attName.length*2;
document.getElementById("cnt").innerHTML +=
        "Number of attribute names and types is "+result;`

Comment: i tried putting 2 more <tr><td>attribute value</td><td><input type="text" id="value5"></td></tr><tr><td>attribute value</td><td><input type="text" id="value6"></td></tr>. and it still shows 2..! it should show 4..

Comment: Oh, i misunderstood you. You need to count inputs, not what user write in them?
Labels 'value' and 'name' confused me. Then `document.querySelectorAll("input").length` will coun all inputs on the page. If you need specific - give them a class and choose by it like `document.querySelectorAll(".specificClass").length`

Comment: I did like this and it works well!! Thanks you so much of your efforts! I wish be like you programmer :)  so talented!

Comment: function javascript_click() {
 if (document.getElementById("value3").value && document.getElementById("value4").value ) {
        var attName=document.getElementById("value3").value;
        var attValue=document.getElementById("value4").value;
        var value = "[" + attName + "=" + attValue + "]";
        var num2 = document.querySelectorAll(value).length;
       
    }}

Answer (score 2):

Every time the user is entering a pair of attributes I'm pushing the attributes in an array `attRy`.

`attRy.length` will give you the number of attributes pairs.

```js
let attRy = []

function javascript_click() { 
  if (value3.value && value4.value ) {
    var attName = value3.value;
    var attValue = value4.value;
    if(attName !=='' && attValue !==''){
      attRy.push(attName + ": " +attValue);
      cnt.innerHTML = attRy.length +" attributes:<br>";
      attRy.forEach((a) =>{
        cnt.innerHTML += a + "<br>"
      })
      
      }
    else {
      cnt.innerHTML += 
      "wrong value of ID <br>";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <table class="tg" id="tg">
    <tr>
      <td>Attribute name</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="value3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>attribute value</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="value4"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div id="cnt"></div>
</form>
<div class="button">
  <button id='btn_javascript' onclick="javascript_click();">javascript</button>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! but in this form, there are 2 of type="text" ! when I operate your code it shows just 1..

Comment: No it doesn't: I have `attRy.push(attName + ": " +attValue);` It shows a pair of attribute name and value